# Transitioning code to RequireJS

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module, requirejs

*TL;DR at the bottom of the question, for those who don't want to read all my junk.*

My current method of JavaScript modularization is to simply create a global anchor, like "csc" (my company acronym) and then start tacking modules onto that.

So I'll end up with a global structure like:

```
csc.
    Utils 
    Map
       .Geolocation
    Storage.
            Cookie
            DB
```

And each of these files are stored in a directory structure:

```
csc.js
csc.Utils.js
csc.Map.js
csc.Storage.js
```

This eliminates the need to load my entire codebase all the time.

I'm trying to transition toward using RequireJS, but the methodology employed by that library seems to be a bit different.

In order to maintain my namespaced structure, I could define modules around all of my modules, but still tack them into the global "csc" reference. However this seems to go against the core principles of Require.

Without keeping them global, however, I lose my nice namespacing, such as "csc.Map.Geolocation" because I now have a bunch of separate variables, like so:

```
require(['csc', 'csc.Utils', 'csc.Map'], function (csc, utils, map) {
});
```

I'll strip my question down to its essence, in case my horrible description above didn't suffice:

**Is there a way, perhaps within the module definitions, to combine these three variables back into the structure defined at the top of this question? Or am I going about this all wrong, and should I instead be adhering to the Require way of doing things?
I'd love to follow the Require methodology, but I also love the ability to have all of my modules chainable and namespaced.**

Comment: One of the main benefits of AMD is to lose the reliance on namespaces. Try to embrace it. There is no technical reason to keep on using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be discouraged by the documentation's example path hierarchy, notice that require does not strictly enforce any particular convention. You are free to design and follow your own convention.

`Utils`, `Map`, and `Storage` all become directories. The base actions that they perform should be named `module.js` in their respective directories, like so:

```
core.js
Utils/
      module.js
Map/
    module.js
    geolocation.module.js
Storage/
        module.js
        cookie.module.js
        db.module.js
```

The `module.js` files include and return their children. Here is an example of Storage/module.js:

```
require(["Storage/cookie", "Storage/db"], function (cookie, db) {
    var Storage = {};
    // do whatever you need with Storage
    Storage.cookie = cookie
    Storage.db = db

    return Storage
});
```

Notice also the `core.js` file in root. This file would work just the same,

```
require(["Utils/module", "Storage/module", "Map/module"], function (utils, storage, map) {
    var Core = {};
    // do whatever you need with Storage
    Core.Utils = utils
    Core.Storage = storage
    Core.Map = map

    return Core
});
```

Now, require core.js wherever you will need access to these modules (every file basically). Yes, this will load all of the involved files all of the time *in development*, but when you compile your app, all of your variables will be inside the scope of an anonymous function, and not directly accessible via the window object.

Again, tweak this as you see fit, it's your own convention.